# Email Sent via root@domain.com despite modifying /etc/aliases

Tags: debian, root, postfix, sendmail

First, here are the entries I added/modified in **/etc/postfix/main.cf** file:

```
mydomain = domain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/amazon-ses
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Now, if I send a test mail like so...

```
$ sudo sendmail someone@gmail.com
To: someone@gmail.com
From: noreply@domain.com
Subject: Test email!
This is just a test email.
.
```

and check the mail log (**/var/log/mail.log**), I see this:

```
Feb 17 04:23:16 hostname postfix/pickup[6226]: B3DD4137ED: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 17 04:23:16 hostname postfix/cleanup[6230]: B3DD4137ED: replace: header From: noreply@domain.com from local; from=<root@domain.com> to=<someone@gmail.com>: From: "WebsiteName Alerts (no reply)" <noreply@domain.com>
Feb 17 04:23:16 hostname postfix/cleanup[6230]: B3DD4137ED: message-id=<20130217042316.B3DD4137ED@hostname.domain.com>
Feb 17 04:23:16 hostname postfix/qmgr[6144]: B3DD4137ED: from=<root@domain.com>, size=353, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 17 04:23:18 hostname postfix/smtp[6232]: B3DD4137ED: to=<someone@gmail.com>, relay=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[107.22.250.234]:25, delay=25, delays=24/0.03/0.93/0.58, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 0000013ce6644ae6-69927d25-c4e1-4f25-8ad4-b85b59318e84-000000)
Feb 17 04:23:18 hostname postfix/qmgr[6144]: B3DD4137ED: removed
```

As you can see, the log shows both `root@domain.com` and `noreply@domain.com` as `from` even though I specifically stated `noreply@domain.com` in the `sendmail` command.

That too, despite modifying my **/etc/aliases** file like so:

```
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: noreply@domain.com
postmaster: noreply@domain.com
nobody: noreply@domain.com
hostmaster: noreply@domain.com
usenet: noreply@domain.com
news: noreply@domain.com
webmaster: noreply@domain.com
www: noreply@domain.com
ftp: noreply@domain.com
abuse: noreply@domain.com
noc: noreply@domain.com
security: noreply@domain.com
root: noreply@domain.com
```

So, the question is, how do I make `noreply@domain.com` the default email address-out for the system? Put it the other way, how do I change the email address of root user from `root@domain.com` to `noreply@domain.com`?

In case this matters, my system's running Debian 7 (Wheezy) 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default return e-mail address other than the user name combined with domain name. As you invoke the sendmail with sudo, it uses the `root` user name to make the envelope return address. To change this behavior use the `-f` switch with sendmail:

```
   -fname Sets the name of the ``from'' person (i.e., the envelope  sender
          of the mail).  This address may also be used in the From: header
          if that header is missing during initial submission.  The  enve‐
          lope sender address is used as the recipient for delivery status
          notifications and may also appear in a Return-Path: header.   -f
          should only be used by ``trusted'' users (normally root, daemon,
          and network) or if the person you are trying to  become  is  the
          same  as  the  person  you are.  Otherwise, an X-Authentication-
          Warning header will be added to the message.
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question. When I send the mail, and the email is received at the other end, I do see that the email is sent by `noreply@domain.com` itself. The thing is, the mail.log shows that the `root@domain.com` for `from` is internally replaced with `noreply@domain.com` before the email is sent. Or does it mean that the root user passes on the email from root@domain.com locally to noreply@domain.com for the latter to send it? Am I clear?

Comment: I am sorry, not really. You typed in the `From:` header already containing `noreply@domain.com` address at submission. The `From:` header and the `envelope from address` is not the same thing. Please check the `Return-Path:` header in the headers of the received e-mail. This address will be used to return any Delivery Status Reports when delivery fails, not the address in the 'From:' header.